# how many outcomes are there if exactly 3 boys win a medal and exactly 15 boys win shirts?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose there are 60 boys and 50 girls racing. There are 5 medals awarded to the top 5 finishers and there are 35 shirts awarded to the first 35 finishers (shirts are identical but medals are not, ie gold, silver, bronze, etc).

How many different outcomes are possible if exactly 3 boys win a medal and 15 boys win shirts? Im really lost on this, please explain to me the thought process required for these kinds of questions.

Thanks!

Comment: You know exactly 3 boys win a medal. So distribute the remaining 2 medals among the girls (50^2) possibilities. 15 boys have shirts, so distribute the remaining shirts among the remaining boys and girls... (remember that everyone who got a medal also got a shirt) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $\binom{5}{3}$ way to choose *which* three medals are awarded to boys, and $60\cdot 59 \cdot 58$ ways to pick out which three boys get what medal.

We've now accounted for three of the $15$ boys to get shirts, we need to see how many ways there are to choose $12$ more from the $57$ remaining boys to recieve just a shirt. Can you do it from here?

Comment: i think i understand, along with the 60*59*58 would you also multilpy 50*49 to account for the remaining medals and then do something similar for the shirts?

Comment: @user161842 Yes, that is correct.